# React context props drilling, what is it that I don't get?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## There is a TL;DR at the bottom.

I am probably doing this wrong or using the context in an bad way. I am new to react so I have no clue if this is how we are meant to do things.

**My understanding:**
Context can be used to pass down props to deeper nested child components without having to pass them through all levels of nesting. A provider is filled with props, and a consumer will look "up the tree" to find the nearest provider and get it's data.
If this is the case, then I can load a provider with a function, such as an onChange handler in order to avoid having to write the handler on every child component when they all do the same thing. This would allow for a "smart form" which govern's its input's handlers by "passing" handlers given to it. Obviously just writing one handler on multiple components is not an issue, but having like 20-30 form fields and writing 4+ handlers on each of them just creates code clutter. So I tried the following:

HTML structure is like this, for example:

```
<ControlledForm data={some_data} handlers={some_handlers}>
    <LabeledControl name="Type your name" rel="Name" meta={{some_meta_object}}></LabeledControl>
    <LabeledControl name="Pet name" rel="PetName" meta={{some_meta_object}}></LabeledControl>
    <LabeledControl name="Type of pet" rel="PetType" meta={{some_meta_object}}></LabeledControl>
    <LabeledControl name="Family" rel="Family" meta={{some_meta_object}}></LabeledControl>
</ControlledForm>
```

And this is the `ControlledForm` class code:

```
const { Provider } = React.createContext(); //Note this

class ControlledForm extends Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider value={{ onChange: this.props.onChange }}>
                <form>{this.props.children}</form>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Now whatever child I place within this form would want to have a `<Consumer>` wrapper around it to consume the `changeHandler`, or at least this is the plan. However when I wrap my `LabeledControl` in a consumer, it acts as if it has no data.

`<LabeledControl>` (reduced code):

```
const { Consumer } = React.createContext();

class LabeledControl extends Component {
    state = {};
    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>
                {r => {
                    console.log("consumer:", r); //Logs undefined
                    return (
                        <div className="labeled-control">
                            {/*Code here*/}
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

If I was to guess at what the issue is, I'd say it is because both the `ControlledForm` and the `LabeledControl` create it's own context, which is not shared, look at the code above. But I do not understand how would I share this context and still keep the two classes in separate .js files. I cannot pass a reference down to the children, all I get is the `{this.props.children}` and no way to tell it "Hey use this provider here". All the examples I find online have the two classes that are a provider and a consumer in a same file, being able to reference the same "context" but this seriously impacts the freedom of what I can put inside a form, or rather doesn't let me have customization in terms of  "children".

## TLDR

How do I pass down a "Context" from a Provider to a Consumer when they are in two different javascript files? Code is above. I essentially need to pass down a handler to every child and have it (maybe, maybe not, depending on a child) use the handler to tell the parent to update it's data. All of this whilst using `{this.props.children}` in a parent in order to allow "outter code" to "inject" the parent component with any children desired and have them either use or not use the parent's handler.

### Edit:

I searched about a bit and found two possible solutions, which I both tested and both seem to be working (with a limited use case). Both **render props** and **React.CloneElement** seem to do the trick when there is one level of nesting as we can directly render and add props to children with them, but when we need to prop drill several levels, all the components in between would have to implement the same passing of props which then turns to spaghetti code. Still searching to try and find the way to pass the context down to the children for consumption in different files.

Comment: There is great example on https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples - you need to export your context and then import it in Label file (instead of creating new context).

Comment: @mwl problem there is, it relies on the fact that there is only ever one context that the components would consume. It is okay when the context is filled with stuff such as "theme color", but not so much when the context holds handlers to manipulate data. In this case every `ControlledForm` would need to make it's own context, and then every `LabeledControl` would have to import all of these, which can't be done in which case I'd need a new "same" component for every different form each consuming its own context, its not really a solution

Answer (score 1):

Please view the code below.

Also: here is a sample project I have built:https://codesandbox.io/s/5z62q8qnox

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default class ControllerForm extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      onChange: this.handleOnChange
    }
  }
  handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value) //here is the place you have to implement
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>

    )
  }

}

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
export default class LabeledControl extends React.Component {

static contextTypes ={
  onChange : PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.context.onChange} />
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ControllerForm>
        <LabeledControl />
        <LabeledControl />
      </ControllerForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I mean, its working, I am just at an awe and do not understand how? o.0 How do you pass the value from Form to Control? Where does the control get it's reference to this.context?

Comment: Okay so upon further reading, I've ran into this context handling. Whilst it does solve the EXACT problem I have, this seems to be on it's way out the door. The next `React.createContext();` however does not solve the issue sadly.

Comment: inside child component I declared static contextType which means I am expecting context data from some ancestor component. And Ancestor component provides this context by declareing static childContextTypes and implementing   getChildContext() function. getChildContext() is provided by React itself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Context` is not what I should be using for this, instead either `render props` or `React.cloneElement()` is the proper solution, despite my best efforts to enforce a context.

**Parent's render:**

```
{this.props.children.map((child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { key: index, handler: handler })
)}
```

**Child's render:**

```
return (
    <div>
        <span onClick={this.props.handler}>{passed.foo}</span>
    </div>
);
```

This way the structure remains clean and handlers get passed down. Only issue is every component that needs to pass them down has to implement this, but it would have been the same with context, since it is not exported to a separate file.